# How to display application cache in android

Tags: android, caching

Hi I'm trying to develop an android app that could list all app's along with their cache size, here is my approach, and my code is working fine now.

```
for(int i=0; i<appCache.size(); i++)
{
try 
{
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Method getPackageSizeInfo;
    getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod("getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);
    getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, appPackageName.get(i), new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {

        @Override
        public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
        throws RemoteException 
        {
            final String title;
            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo;
            try {
                applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(pStats.packageName, 0);
                title = (String)((applicationInfo != null) ? packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo) : "???");
                MessageDetails Detail;
                Detail = new MessageDetails();
                Detail.setIcon(getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon( pStats.packageName ));
                Detail.setName(title);
                Detail.setSub("Cache Size -> "+(pStats.cacheSize/1024));
                details.add(Detail);
            } 
            catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {}
        }
    });
} 
catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}       
}
```

But here all app's installed in device gets listed along with their cache, but I want to filter the list to those app's whose cache size is greater than 0, please help me to solve this riddle, Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you filter before adding to your list?

Comment: I tried, but when I filtered only recently calculated `cache size > 0` lists in the UI @Chintan Rathod

Comment: @ChethanShetty  i m also facing same issue can u pls tell me how u resolved your issue when i m trying to put condition inside onGetStatsCompleted  and filtering data so i m getting error in my listview that listview is adding data from the background thread

Comment: heyy i also want to do same so plz let us know how u get  for loop "appCache"